# On a Bessel Inequality proof

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, orthogonality

I've been working on a couple of algebra identities' demonstrations, among which the Bessel inequality. Here is the problem set:

We consider a vector space $V$, a vector $u$ in $V$, a subspace $E$ of $V$ of dimension $n$ and a basis $B$ for $E$ such that $B=\{u_1, u_2, ..., u_n\}$.

The orthogonal projection of $u$ on $E$, named $v$, is given by

$v=\sum_{i=1}^n {\lt u,u_i \gt\over \lt u_i,u_i \gt}\cdot u_i$

We define the vector $w$ as $u-v$ (hence $w$ is orthogonal to $E$).

We want to prove that

$||u||^2\geq \sum_{i=1}^n ({\lt u,u_i \gt^2\over \lt u_i, u_i \gt})\cdot u_i$ (Bessel Inequality)

By the generalization of the Pythagorean Theorem, we have:

$ \begin{align}
{\|u\|}^2 & = {\|w\|}^2 + {\|v\|}^2 \\ 
& = {\|w\|}^2 + {\|\sum_{i=1}^n {\lt u,u_i \gt\over \lt u_i,u_i \gt}\cdot u_i \|}^2 \\ 
\end{align}$

Hence,

$ {\|u\|}^2 \geq {\|\sum_{i=1}^n {\lt u,u_i \gt\over \lt u_i,u_i \gt}\cdot u_i \|}^2  $

But I'm stuck here. I have to show that

$ {\|\sum_{i=1}^n {\lt u,u_i \gt\over \lt u_i,u_i \gt}\cdot u_i \|}^2 = {\sum_{i=1}^n ({\lt u,u_i \gt^2\over \lt u_i, u_i \gt})\cdot u_i}$

And I don't know how. I have tried the inner product properties, but I just do not understand how the norm squared gives this sum. I hope you can help me on this.

By the way, as this is my first time using MathJax, sorry for any errors in my format style. Thank you.

Comment: The $u_i$ need to be orthogonal.

Comment: yes I forgot to specify that the basis has to be orthogonal

Comment: It certainly helps when computing the norm of your sum....

Comment: Some tips regarding mathjax: for angled brackets, use `\langle` and `rangle` to get $\langle$ and $\rangle$ rather than $<$ and $>$.  As far as fractions go, I prefer to use `\frac{P}{Q}` rather than `{P \over Q}` especially for complicated expressions, but both work. Other than that, you can look at the code I used to type things up by clicking the edit button on my question (and clicking cancel if you don't want to change anything).  You can also right-click an expression and select "Show Math As... TeX Commands" from the resulting menu.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I'm afraid I don't quite understand how to use the fact that it is orthogonal to show what I'm trying to show. Could you enlighten me on this?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thanks for your advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to see that 
$
{\|\sum_{i=1}^n {\lt u,u_i \gt\over \lt u_i,u_i \gt}\cdot u_i \|}^2 = {\sum_{i=1}^n ({\lt u,u_i \gt^2\over \lt u_i, u_i \gt})\cdot u_i},
$ it suffices to (inductively) use the generalization of the Pythagorean theorem.  In particular,
$$
\left\|\sum_{i=1}^n {\langle u,u_i \rangle\over \langle u_i,u_i \rangle}\cdot u_i \right\|^2 = 
\left\|\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} {\langle u,u_i \rangle\over \langle u_i,u_i \rangle}\cdot u_i \right) + {\langle u,u_n \rangle\over \langle u_n,u_n \rangle}\right\|^2
\\= \left\|\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} {\langle u,u_i \rangle\over \langle u_i,u_i \rangle}\cdot u_i\right\|^2
+ 
\left\|{\langle u,u_n \rangle\over \langle u_n,u_n \rangle} \cdot u_n\right\|^2
$$

From there, note that (by the homogeneity of norms)
$$
\left\|{\langle u,u_n \rangle\over \langle u_n,u_n \rangle} \cdot u_n\right\|^2 = 
\left| {\langle u,u_n \rangle\over \langle u_n,u_n \rangle} \right|^2 \cdot \|u_n\|^2 = \frac{|\langle u,u_n \rangle|^2}{\langle u_n,u_n \rangle} \cdot \langle u_n,u_n \rangle = |\langle u,u_n\rangle|^2.
$$

Comment: I don't understand how this use of the generalized Pythagorean theorem helps us to prove what I'm trying to prove. I have to say I would be tempted to use the definition of the norm to find what I'm trying to find, but the thing is I would obtain a the inner product of vectors defined themselves with the inner product, which is confusing to me. Could you enlighten me on your process?

Comment: See my latest edit.